# How to use RequireJS to insert script tag in a div instead of the head?

Tags: javascript, requirejs

RequireJs by default, inserts the script tags in the head. 
How can I force it to insert the script tag inside a specific div. 
So instead of:

```
requirejs([someScript], function(util) {
        console.log("requireJS inserting someScript in the head");
});
```

If I can do:

```
requirejs([someScript], someDivID,function(util) {
        console.log("requireJS inserting someScript in #someDivID");
});
```

Comment: Why do you need to do this? (What underlying problem would be solved if the script were added to the div?)

Comment: The downloaded 3rd-party script would only run correctly if its parent has a specific ID.